# Facebook FQL to collect stats for all pages on a website, not just the homepage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm currently using:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count,
total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count
FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.mediauk.com/'
```

...to collect Facebook link stats for a specific website.

Of course, this only does one page; and would miss, for example, any Facebook stats for http://www.mediauk.com/jobs

Is there a way I can use wildcards or something similar to group all URLs from one domain together?

Answer (score 0):

If You are using somekind of a CMS, you proppably can do a loop throught all pages/posts/whatever and then collect all information.
If it is a normal html service coded manually, than beside a creation of an array with all links and then get those data for them, proppably there is no other answer :(.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP I'd do this:

```
<?php 

$fb_links = array();

//THEN POPULATE ARRAY WITH LINKS YOU GET FROM YOUR DB
...
//AND FINALLY CREATE FACEBOOK QUERY USING "IN" TOGETHER WITH PHP's implode() 

$fql = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count
FROM link_stat 
WHERE url IN ('".implode("','",$fb_links)."')";

echo $fql; 

// Result will be: SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN ('link1','link2','link3')

?>
```

EDIT: just a typo